# proccessing input interactively from command line using VBscript

Tags: shell, vbscript, wsh

I am trying to read input interactively from a command prompt using VBScript, But I can't seem to read the data using readLine() in order to later send a reply.

Here's the code I have tried:

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For i=1 To 500
  If i=450 Then Exit For
OBJECT.SendKeys "00LI002LE99{ENTER}" 
WScript.sleep 2000 
dim input=ReadLine()
If input="LI002LE99" Then OBJECT.SendKeys "OK{ENTER}"

OBJECT.SendKeys "00LI002LE00{ENTER}" 
WScript.sleep 2000 
Next
```

The idea with this code is that if I were to send the command `00LI002LE99` on the command line,  I want to send a console reply of `LI002LE99`. How can I get my script to read the data using the readline() command and then send the appropriate response?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure why you would want to do this, but there are a few problems with your code:

1. I'd recommend avoiding using the name `OBJECT` for variables.
2. You can't use `dim` like that in vbscript. You have to split it out into multiple instructions. What language do you normally use?
3. The way you are trying to use `Readline()` just won't work.

Here's a working example of your script, but be aware that if you move focus away from the the command window, strange things may happen! (eg: the send keys instruction will output the results to whichever window has the current focus - which I would imagine is not the desired outcome, if you are tabbing between windows or something):

```
Option Explicit

Dim shell, i, input        

set shell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For i=1 To 500
     If i=450 Then Exit For
     shell.SendKeys "00LI002LE99{ENTER}" 
     WScript.sleep 2000 
     input = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine() 
     If input="00LI002LE99" Then shell.SendKeys "OK{ENTER}"
     shell.SendKeys "00LI002LE00{ENTER}" 
     WScript.sleep 2000 
Next
```

Best of luck. Again, not entirely sure what you're doing here :) 
FYI: The Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine() is going to be a little hit and miss.